# Changing URL hash value when one page scrolling menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

I have a one page scrolling script.

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $('.nav li a').bind('click',function(event){
                    var $anchor2 = $(this).parent();
                    var $anchor = $(this);
                    $('.nav  li').removeClass('active');
                    $anchor2.addClass('active');


                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
                    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

The above script works perfect. But the typical URL in the address bar as follows

```
example.com/index.html
example.com/index.html#about
example.com/index.html#contact
```

I would like to change this URL to something more neat and usable like

```
example.com/about
example.com/contact
```

If the above URL accessed directly, It should be in the same scroll position. How can we do it in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)  and   [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.title)

```
$('.nav li').on('click', 'a', function(event){
       if ($(this).parent("li").hasClass("active")){
        return false;
       }else{
        var go2hash = $(this).attr("data-hash");
        $(this).parent("li").addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");
        document.title = go2hash;
        location.hash = go2hash;
        event.preventDefault();
       }
});
```

with anchor like :

```
 <nav>
      <li><a data-hash=home>home</a></li>
      <li><a data-hash=work>work</a></li>
      <li><a data-hash=contact>contact</a></li>
 <nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Apache and are only concerned with cleaner URLs from outside your site, you could use ModRewrite rules in an .htaccess file placed in your root directory.

This example would redirect requests for example.com/contact to example.com/#contact and load the page at the correct section.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /#$1 [R,NE,L]
```

Once inside the site, the hashes will be back. I don't know if that's a deal breaker in your case.